# Titanium download and save a file locally and show it in an ImageView

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

I would like to download a file (public URL) and save it to my application directory

```
Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory
```

Now if I would want to show that image in an **ImageView** what will be the path I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 var photoFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, <Your Image Name with .png or .jpg>);

    var blobOfImage = photoFile.read();

                var imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                    image : blobOfImage,
                    width : 'auto',
                    height : 'auto'
                });
```

I think this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks! Giving it a shot.